# Google Apps Script: Unexpected exception when parsing email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a script which take a group's email in input and parse all members to add them in a CSV document.

The Problem is that some of my groups contain other groups so i have to call recursively my function. And to call it recursivelly i need to test the email address to know if its a user or a group.
Here the code:

```
var USERS = new Array();
var INDEX = 0;


function listAllUsersInGroup(email) {
  var temporaryObjectListMember = GroupsManager.getGroup(email).getAllMembers();
  for (z=0; z<temporaryObjectListMember.length; z++) {
    try {
      var group = GroupsManager.getGroup(temporaryObjectListMember[z]);
    }
    catch (err2){Logger.log(err2)}
    if (group != null) { listAllUsersInGroup(group.getId());}
    else {
      try {
        var user = UserManager.getUser(temporaryObjectListMember[z].substring(0,temporaryObjectListMember[z].lastIndexOf('@')));
      } catch(err) { Logger.log(err) }

      if (user != null) {
        USERS[INDEX] = user.getEmail();
        INDEX++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I call this function with a main:

```
function main() {
  var email = "grouptest@domain.com";
  listAllUsersInGroup(email);
}
```

When the group contain users and an another group, it broke with an "Unexpected exception upon serializing continuation" error.

The try catch does'nt seem to work in this case.

One solution could be to test the type of the email (user, group, alias, ...) but i haven't find how to do this.

Thanks
Jérémie BECOUSSE

Comment: Hi Jérémie. I've looked into this a bit, and I do believe there's a bug here. Would you mind opening an issue on the [Google Apps Script issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)? Thanks!

Comment: Hello,
Following your advice, i've opened a Issue (n°2534)

If someone know another method to detect if an email adress is a user or a group or alias, i'll take it! :-)

Thanks

Comment: Great, thanks! We are working on a fix.

Answer (score 1):

after little modifications of your script it seems to be correctly working.

when you create a google group the list of the members will automatically be cut of all the aliases so there is no problem with those.
you have to check if you are facing other groups Or email adresses that can be from 2 types:
email from your domain --> you can find it out with the user manager function
email from outside your domain --> I dont believe there is a way to know if they are valid before sending something to those

the next code will return in "USERS" users from your domain and in "EXTUSER" user that are not from your domain. (run testingIt())

```
 function listAllUsersInGroup(email) {
  var temporaryObjectListMember = GroupsManager.getGroup(email).getAllMembers();
  for (var z in temporaryObjectListMember) {
    var member = temporaryObjectListMember[z];
    try {
      var group = GroupsManager.getGroup(member);
    }
    catch (err2){
      //Logger.log("is not group: "+err2);
    }

    if (group != null) { 
      Logger.log(member+" is a group");
      listAllUsersInGroup(member);
    }
    else {
      try {
        var user = UserManager.getUser(member.split('@')[0]);
      } catch(err) { 
        //Logger.log("it's not a known mail: "+err);
        EXTUSERS.push(member);
      }

      if (user != null) {
        USERS.push(member);
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log("end of the group");
}

var EXTUSERS = [];
var USERS = [];


function testingIt(){
  listAllUsersInGroup("groupemailadress@domain.ext");
  Logger.log("recognized users are: "+USERS);
  Logger.log("unrecognized users are: "+EXTUSERS);
}
```