# geteditors not returning emails the ui decides is a group

Tags: google-apps-script

So you create a document in drive, then share it.  You share it to someone inside google's network, the email address gets an icon of a single dude.  But if you share it with someone outside of googles network, you get an icon of multiple dudes.  At least you do when you share it with security set to anyone with the link can get in.  Im not sure if this works in the other modes.

but anyways, you now write an app script that wants to send an email to everyone the file is shared with.  so you use DocsList to get the file, then call the getEditors method to get the list of people that the file is shared with.  The problem is it looks like that method only returns the email addresses with the icon of the single dude.  How do I get the other email addresses?

If that can't happen, how do I tell Drive that the external email address I'm adding is in fact a person and not a group?

Answer (score 0):

I think that happened because you shared to someone that do not have a google account.
In order to see the document with an identified ID they must have a google account (that do not mean a google email adress) You can create an account associated to your email adress [here](https://accounts.google.com/NewAccount?hl=FR)

for the second part of the question you can refer to that previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346991/google-apps-script-unexpected-exception-when-parsing-email/15386405#15386405)

Comment: i was really hoping that wasn't the answer.  this application is getting to be a monsterous pain in the a@@ due to all these little pain points.  I wish google had spent a few hours of thought and made these controls more usable.  Then again i wouldn't have to even write the stupid app if there was a checkbox that notified users of a new or updated file in a folder thats shared with them